# How to get to the maximum value before executing code in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, if-statement

I have this programming problem, I'm using C#. I want to check if varA is less than 8 then execute the code which decreases the value, like this

```
//intial
float varA = 0.0f;

if(varA <= 8.0f){

varA -= 2.0f;

}
```

This code works fine, but the problem is that if varA is less than 8 then I want it to increase up it to 8 first then start decreasing.

For instance, if the varA equals 6 then it should be increased to 8 and then start decreasing. Hopefully you have got what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: by the way this code runs inside a loop, and varA will keep changing throughout!! :))

Comment: how does varA reach 8 (or change outside the snippet you showed) ? A timer ? A periodic call ?

Comment: its an update loop(game engine :) ) so it keeps updating every second, varA will keep changing, incase it reaches the value 8, i want to do something with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a flag to tell you when to start running your subtraction code.

```
Boolean doIt = false;

// your outer loop
{
  if (varA ==8.0f) {
    doIt = true;
  }

  if ((doIt) && (varA <= 8.0f)) {
    varA -= 2.0f;
  }
}
```

of course, the main problem above is what happens if varA is 9.0.  In this case, it will not decrease but that may or may not matter to you.

Comment: i have to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer!! sorry im stupid sometimes

Comment: more a wild guess that just happened to be what you where after

Answer (score 0):

You're correct - your question is a bit confusing. It seems like you need a simple if/else:

```
if(varA <= 8.0f) {
    varA -= 2.0f;
}
else {
    varA += 2.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean...

```
if(varA <= 8.0f){
    // do stuff with varA being 8.0 eg
    myFunc(varA);
    varA -= 2.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the question right,

```
varA = varA >= 8.0 ? varA -= 2.0f : varA += 2.0f;
```

Comment: fairly sure you want `varA <= 8.0`

Comment: If `varA` less then 8 it would decrease, otherwise increase, am I missed something?

Comment: you currently have if `var is greater then or equal to 8.0 reduce varA else increase varA`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that, you are trying to do this in an infinite loop.

```
bool localMaximumReached = false;    
        while (true)
        {
            if (varA < 8.0f)
            {
                if (!localMaximumReached)
                {
                    varA += 1.0f;
                    if (varA >= 8.0f)
                        localMaximumReached = true;
                }
                else
                    varA -= 2.0f;
            }
            else
                break;
         }
```